# TS2531 | React useRef - Object is possibly undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-google-maps

I need to set new lat and lng to my google map in React

Const mapRef return error: **Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531**
When i used let instead of the React.useRef it works. 
I think a should set type to mapRef, but i dont know which one and where i can find it.
But I think useRef is better solution, isnt it?

Google maps library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

```
const libraries = ["places"];

const CustomMap = () => {
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
    libraries,
  });

  const options = {
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
  };

  const mapRef = React.useRef();
  const onMapLoad = React.useCallback((map) => {
    mapRef.current = map;
  }, []);

  const panTo = React.useCallback(({ lat, lng }) => {
    if (null !== mapRef.current) {
      // There is error 
      // mapRef.current Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531
      mapRef.current.panTo({ lat, lng });
      mapRef.current.setZoom(18);
    }
  }, []);
  //console.log("maps show coord: ", props.coordinates);

  if (loadError) {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <p>Error</p>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
  if (!isLoaded) {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <p>loading</p>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Search panTo={panTo} />
      <GoogleMap
        id="map"
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        zoom={15}
        center={center}
        //options={options}
        onLoad={onMapLoad}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What library are you using for the `GoogleMap` component?

Comment: @RodrigoEhlers Google maps library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

Answer (score 5):

Use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-map-react) to find the types, then set the type for `useRef` and initialise it with `null`.

```js
const mapRef: Type = React.useRef(null); // Replace `Type` with the actual type from the package
```

in your case the type seems to be `google.maps.Map` so

```js
const mapRef: google.maps.Map = React.useRef(null);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I cannot find right types.
But when i tried this:
 `let mapRef: google.maps.Map;` It works. But this type for useRef<> doesnt work.

Comment: @HonzaVrkota I updated the answer so the next person knows how to do it. Would be nice if you can accept the answer.

Comment: I tried this `const mapRef: google.maps.Map = React.useRef(null);`.
But it returns new error `Type 'MutableRefObject<null>' is missing the following properties from type 'Map<Element>': addListener, fitBounds, getBounds, getCenter, and 31 more.  TS2740`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the type should be defined in React.useRef(), and it's only possible to know that if you tell what is the library you're using for the map. But before you tell that, try to research on the library documentation.

And about the null error, referencing [this](http://When%20you%20create%20a%20invoke%20a%20useRef%20hook,%20it%E2%80%99s%20important%20to%20pass%20null%20as%20the%20default%20value.%20%20This%20is%20important%20because%20React.useRef%20can%20only%20be%20null,%20or%20the%20element%20object.) article

> When you create a invoke a useRef hook, it’s important to pass null as the default value.

So the definition should be something like:

```
const mapRef = React.useRef<TheTypeYouNeed>(null);
```

Comment: Google maps library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

Answer (score 0):

Solution is this:
Type for map instance is: **google.maps.Map**
Google maps library: [npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api](http://npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api)

```
 const mapRef = useRef<google.maps.Map>();
 const onMapLoad = React.useCallback((map: google.maps.Map) => {
    mapRef.current = map;
    if (defaultLocation !== null && props.place_id !== "") {
      setCoords(defaultLocation);
      setDefaultZoom(14);
      map.panTo(defaultLocation);
      try {
        FetchPlaceDetail(props.place_id, map, props.setPlaceDetail);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }, []);

...

mapRef.current?.panTo({ lat, lng });
```